# Regex for validating dd/mm/yyyy with optional time

Tags: regex

I want a regex which will validate that dates are in one of the following formats:

- dd/MM/yyyy
- dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm
- dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss

So far I have got

```
^([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])\/([0]\d|[1][0-2])\/[1-2]\d{3}((\s([0-1]\d|[2][0-3])\:[0-5]\d\((:[0-5]\d)?)?)$
```

which I have been trying in [an online regex tester](http://regex101.com/). The input matches when I try `21/05/2014` but not `21/05/2014 15:54` or `21/05/2014 15:54:12`

It's probably a misplaced ? error, but with my limited regex skills it looks correct to me.

Note that I am not looking to be overly fussy about things like leap years and days in the month. [01-31]/[01-12]/[1000-2999] is fine for the date part.

Comment: Are you sure regex is the right tool for the job? Regex is great for validating the *format*, but if you want to check whether the date is valid you should use a date library (for whichever language this may be) anyway, and it'll probably be able to do the parsing as well.

Comment: @Biffen regex is the right tool for the job as it is not used in code. It is a pattern to go into a .json schema for validating csv files using [CSV Lint](http://csvlint.io/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your expression for time, you are trying to match a literal open parenthesis:

```
((\s([0-1]\d|[2][0-3])\:[0-5]\d\((:[0-5]\d)?)?)
                               ^^
```

If you remove that, you should be good. However, I cleaned up some of these match groups a bit..so 1 is day, 2 is month, 3 is year, 4 is hour, 5 is minute, 6 is second:

```
^([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])\/([0]\d|[1][0-2])\/([1-2]\d{3})(?:(?:\s([0-1]\d|[2][0-3])\:([0-5]\d)(?::([0-5]\d))?)?)$
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/dF1jZ3)

However, with an expression this complicated, it may be worth using the `x` modifier and adding whitespace & comments with `(?# ... )`.

---

Finally, may I suggest something [much simpler](http://regex101.com/r/sT4cF4) like:

```
^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}\s*(?:\d{2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?)?$
```

This is easier to read/modify/debug, and will still match the same group of numbers.  Than you can use your language's (PHP, Java, Javascript, Python, etc) libraries to *attempt* to create a DateTime class.  If it fails, then you know its an invalid date.  This will be even more accurate as well, since your expression will still match `30/02/2014` which is not a day.

Comment: `\s*(?:` → `(?:\s*` to not allow trailing whitespace if its just a date.